# Arquillian persistence extension test dont see dataset

Tags: java, maven, jpa, jboss-arquillian, apache-tomee

I trying to work with tests using arquillian persistence extension with TomEE Embedded container, but in my test case - provided dataset seems not to be invoking.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<groupId>com.mycompany.mvd</groupId>
<artifactId>hr-model</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.arquillian.universe</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${version.junit}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.arquillian.universe</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-persistence</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.arquillian.universe</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-transaction-jta</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-transaction-jta</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-tomee-embedded</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-universe</artifactId>
            <version>${version.arquillian_universe}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<properties>
    <version.arquillian_universe>1.0.0.Alpha3</version.arquillian_universe>
    <version.junit>4.12</version.junit>
</properties>
```

I have simple entity class

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

@Id
private Long id;

private String value;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
}
```

arquillian.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
<container qualifier="server" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="httpsPort">-1</property>
        <property name="httpPort">-1</property>
        <property name="stopPort">-1</property>

        <property name="properties">
            jdbc/TestDB = new://Resource?type=DataSource
            jdbc/TestDB.JdbcDriver = org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
            jdbc/TestDB.JdbcUrl = jdbc:hsqldb:mem:arquillian
            jdbc/TestDB.UserName = sa
            jdbc/TestDB.Password =
            jdbc/TestDB.JtaManaged = true
            jdbc/TestDB.LogSql = true
        </property>
    </configuration>
</container>

<extension qualifier="persistence">
    <property name="defaultDataSource">openejb:Resource/jdbc/TestDB</property>
</extension>
```

The dataset file:

```
<dataset>
<myentity id="1" value="Test"/>
<myentity id="2" value="Test2"/>
<myentity id="3" value="Test3"/>
</dataset>
```

And the test case, that isn't working:

```
@Test
@Transactional(TransactionMode.COMMIT)
@UsingDataSet("datasets/myentity.xml")
@InSequence(5)
public void shouldFindInDataset() {
    MyEntity entity = entityManager.find(MyEntity.class, 2L);
    System.out.println(entity);
    Assert.assertNotNull(entity);
    Assert.assertEquals("Test2", entity.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is your dataset file located?

Comment: @bartosz.majsak they are located as expected in src/test/resources/datasets

Comment: So it seems to be some problem with TomEE-embedded or OpenJPA, dunno. But exactly same version (except TomEE configuration properties) is working for my managed WildFly with H2 database and Hibernate provider. But I need some embedded version, cause we are now working on setup CI server (TeamCity) and I need tests, that will work there. Of course, we can use remote testing server or install managed version on TeamCity server, but basically I want to overcome this problem for future.

Comment: @bartosz.majsak and thanks for yours very helpful examples on programcreek)